# SwiftUI: Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot?' has no member 'document'

Tags: swift, string, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

When trying to fetch a user, I am getting the error: "Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot?' has no member 'document'". The error occurs on the line that starts "let uid....".

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

// Global Refernce

let ref = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchUser(uid: String,completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> ()){
    
    ref.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument { (doc, err) in
        guard let user = doc else{return}
        
        let username = user.data()?["username"] as? String ?? "No Username"
        let pic = user.data()?["imageurl"] as? String ?? "No image URL"
        let bio = user.data()?["bio"] as? String ?? "No bio"
        let uid = doc.document.data()["uid"] as! String ?? 
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(UserModel(username: username, pic: pic, bio: bio, uid: uid))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `uid` a field in document? Then you can just change the uid line to `let uid = user.data()?["uid"] as? String ?? "No uid"`. Or are you trying to read ID of the document? In that case you can `doc.documentID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `uid` is a field like others `username` and `imageurl` then use

```
let uid = user.data()["uid"] as? String ?? ""
```

if you have made that uid as id of the document then use

```
let uid = doc.documentID
```

See [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot)